# access module settings from custom class

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am having trouble in DotNetNuke 7 accessing module settings using

```
Settings["mySetting"].ToString();
```

from a method in a custom partial class which inherits "myModuleBase". I am using a module development template that already has a partial class defined called "view" and "edit" which inherit myModuleBase and are able to get module settings using the above.

I don't understand where the problem lies.

Comment: Can you post the error message? Does it let you inherit from PortalModuleBase instead?

Comment: Brian, thanks for the help, The error is a null object reference. and no I can not inherit from portal module base.

Answer (score 2):

I received this answer on DNN Community Exchange so I thought I would post it here in case it help someone else

courtesy of Chris Hammond, Director of Training at DotnetNuke

> In order to access the settings make sure you have the
>   ModuleConfiguration being passed over to the other class.
>
> You can see an example of this with my Simple Article module
>
> http://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/20228#83727

```
var controlToLoad = "Controls/ArticleList.ascx";
if (ArticleId > 0) {
    controlToLoad = "Controls/ArticleView.ascx";
}
var mbl = (dnnsimplearticleModuleBase)LoadControl(controlToLoad);
mbl.ModuleConfiguration = ModuleConfiguration;
mbl.ID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(controlToLoad);
phViewControl.Controls.Add(mbl);
```

Comment: finally found the solution!